# How to draw a triangle shaped UIButton

Tags: ios, uibutton, core-graphics, cgcontext

I really dig the IFTTT bottom right corner button, as shown in the image (bottom right).

[image]

I tried playing around with `CGContext` and `UIBezierPath` to match the effect, but i simply don't know enough to get this right. Does anyone have some thoughts/code on how to make this happen?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First use a CAShapeLayer to create a mask

```
CAShapeLayer * shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
//Use these to create path
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
// CGPathMoveToPoint
// CGPathAddLines
shapeLayer.path = path;
```

Then set mask of your button

```
yourbutton.layer.mask = shapeLayer
yourbutton.masksToBounds = YES;
```

Example of a view

```
  CAShapeLayer * shapeLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, nil, 0, CGRectGetHeight(self.testview.frame));
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, CGRectGetWidth(self.testview.frame), 0);
CGPathAddLineToPoint(path, nil, CGRectGetWidth(self.testview.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.testview.frame));
CGPathCloseSubpath(path);
shapeLayer.path = path;
self.testview.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
self.testview.layer.mask = shapeLayer;
```

And screen shot:

[image]

Comment: Note that touch tracking will still act as if the button is a square, this may not matter, but is worth noting nevertheless.

Answer (score 0):

Make a square button, put an image of triangle in it. Won't that work too? To make the illusion even better, draw separate images for onclick() event and ontouch(). Disable the default button press and button click animations to make it look real.

Comment: Personally I'm not an iOS programmer so I do not know the core APIs, but when I want a button with different shapes, That's what I usually do.