# UIButton touch event overlap

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I need to make UIButton pattern like follwing screenshot. My problem is if i do set frame normally and set image to button frame. Touch event get overlapping.

I am using follwing code,

```
UIButton *button1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button1 addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button1 setImage:[UIImage imageWithName:@"Triangle1.png"]];
button1.frame = CGRectMake(100.0, 100.0, 150.0, 150.0);
[view addSubview:button1];

UIButton *button2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button2 addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod1:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button2 setImage:[UIImage imageWithName:@"Triangle2.png"]];
button2.frame = CGRectMake(175.0, 100.0, 150.0, 150.0);// if set X to 250 then pattern not seems 
[view addSubview: button2];

UIButton *button3 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button3 addTarget:self 
           action:@selector(aMethod2:)
 forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button3 setImage:[UIImage imageWithName:@"Triangle2.png"]];
button3.frame = CGRectMake(150.0, 260.0, 150.0, 150.0);// if set X to 250 then pattern not seems 
[view addSubview: button3];
```

One my Senior is telling me, i need to use CALayer , I have read but honestely i am not able to understand there stuffs.

**Any help is very much appreciated.**

Comment: Why don't you set image as button title image ???

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30315337/how-to-draw-a-triangle-shaped-uibutton

Comment: Sir you mean i have to set titleEdgeInset ? But still touch even overlapping

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please, learn how to ask a good question! http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. What is missing is something more specific about your issue besides not understanding what a CALayer is. (If that's what's the real issue.)

Comment: thank you anbu.karthik, i will try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `OBShapedButton` library its free of cost, Drag `OBShapedButton.h` & `OBShapedButton.m` class in your project.& thereafter `OBShapedButton.h` in your VC.h file where you want use buttons,

```
#import "OBShapedButton.h"

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet OBShapedButton *yourCustomButton;
```

**Objective-C**

Drag & place UIButton's on storyboard of your matching pattern change each button Custom class `UIButton` to `OBShapedButton` in class identifier & create instance in the or drag outlet in the VC.h file.

```
[yourCustomButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"customImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**& for swift you can use BridgeHeader**

Comment: Please add the library link. I would like to upvote it.

Answer (score 1):

**Karn**  suggested OBShapedButton library worked for me in Objective C, Touch events works perfectly.

I have Used [OBShapedButton](https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton) library & its free of cost. Brilliant demo by **[Ole Begemann](https://oleb.net/blog/2009/10/obshapedbutton-non-rectangular-buttons-on-the-iphone/)**

> Download library add two folders(having OBShapedButton.h & OBShapedButton.m, UIImage+ColorAtPixel.h , UIImage+ColorAtPixel.m) called `OBShapedButton` & `UIImage+ColorAtPixel` to your project & Inside your viewcontroller on storyboard give class attribute instead UIButtons as OBShapedButton then drag the outlet to your `YourViewController.h`.

```
#import "OBShapedButton.h"

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet OBShapedButton *obsButtonTest;
```

then,

```
[obsButtonTest setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

**For swift you can use BridgingHeader**

And In bridging header you can import following two classes

```
#import "OBShapedButton.h"
#import "UIImage+ColorAtPixel.h"
```

Drag outlet from storyboard to your viewcontroller.swift file

```
@IBOutlet weak var obsButtonTest: OBShapedButton!
```

Set image from stroyboard itself or set it programmatically,

```
obsButtonTest.setImage(.image_name, for: .normal)
```

[image: Triangular shape button screen]